# How to select count as a percentage over the total in Oracle using any Oracle function?

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have an SQL statement that counts over the total number of rows active packages whose end date is null.  I am currently doing this using `(x/y) * 100`:

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) 
          FROM packages 
         WHERE end_dt IS NULL) / (SELECT COUNT(*) 
                                    FROM packages) * 100 
  FROM DUAL;
```

I wonder if there is a way to make use of any Oracle function to express this more easily?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no functionality I'm aware of, but you could simply the query to be:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN p.end_dt IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / COUNT(*) * 100
  FROM PACKAGES p
```

Comment: @OMG:  I think you want SUM, not COUNT, and flip the 1 & 0 around (or say not null)

Comment: Hi Gerrat, yep, SUM is correct, but the 1 & 0 is correct. Thanks!

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Or you could change the ELSE part to `ELSE NULL` (or omit it).

Comment: @Andriy M: I remember Oracle returning `NULL` when doing math operations & a value is `NULL`, but I don't have an instance handy to test.

Comment: Also, try `(a * 100.0) / b` to both cause an implicit cast to a non-integer type, and avoid rounding errors.

Comment: @Chin: Well, you did say: "over the total number of rows active packages whose end date is `not` null".  I didn't look closeley enough at your actual sql (which is doing the opposite).

Comment: @OMG Ponies: You are right, but aggregates treat NULLs a bit differently: they just ignore them. In any event, I meant using `ELSE NULL` with COUNT, not with SUM. When the condition is met, the CASE would return a value, otherwise it would return NULL. Consequently, COUNT would count only the ocurrences when the condition was met.

Answer (score 6):

So, basically the formula is

```
COUNT(NULL-valued "end_dt") / COUNT(*) * 100
```

Now, `COUNT(NULL-valued "end_dt")` is syntactically wrong, but it can be represented as `COUNT(*) - COUNT(end_dt)`. So, the formula can be like this:

```
(COUNT(*) - COUNT(end_dt)) / COUNT(*) * 100
```

If we just simplify it a little, we'll get this:

```
SELECT (1 - COUNT(end_dt) * 1.0 / COUNT(*)) * 100 AS Percent
FROM packages
```

<s>The `* 1.0` bit converts the integer result of `COUNT` to a non-integer value so make the division non-integer too.</s>

The above sentence and the corresponding part of the script turned out to be complete rubbish. Unlike some other database servers, Oracle does not perform integer division, even if both operands are integers. [This doc page](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/operators002.htm#sthref870) contains no hint of such behaviour of the division operator.

Comment: +1, but...  Need a conversion of `a/b` to use a non integer type?  (Be it implicit or explicit)

Comment: @Dems: You are probably right. I know for sure that SQL Server would definitely need this. I'll modify my answer then.

Comment: `100.0 - (100.0 * COUNT(end_dt) / COUNT(*))`?

Comment: @Dems: Ah, I was torn between that formula and the one I eventually posted. *Maybe* yours is slightly better. :)

Comment: Oracle 10g yields the same answer with or without the extra 1.0 multiplication factor.

Answer (score 3):

The original post is a little long in the tooth but this should work, using the function "**ratio_to_report**" that's been available since Oracle 8i:

```
SELECT
  NVL2(END_DT, 'NOT NULL', 'NULL') END_DT,
  RATIO_TO_REPORT(COUNT(*)) OVER () AS PCT_TOTAL
FROM
  PACKAGES
GROUP BY
  NVL2(END_DT, 'NOT NULL', 'NULL');
```